# 3yo need to hold my hands to sleep during the night

Tags: sleep

I used to hold my son's hands when he was 2-3months for helping him sleep longer at night, but I never knew it will give him a habit to MUST sleep with my hands.

I don't mind to hold his hands to make him sleep at all. The thing is he still wake up 3-4 or 4-5 times at night and he needs to cuddle my hands or arm to back to sleep. I never have one through night sleep ever since he's born. I have to work during the day too. He is so attached to me that I can't even take a shift with my husband because he will cry for me during the night.

I've tried everything by giving him night light, stuffed toys, or blankets etc. nothing works....

I really miss my through-the-night sleep. (T-T). And I really need all of your opinions to help. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Very gradually, and very gently, try to reduce the amount of physical contact you're using to comfort your son. By this I mean, if he's cuddling your arm, gradually reduce this to just your hand, then just a finger, and then eventually he'll hopefully be happy to just have your next to him.

Don't do it in a way that causes him distress though, as this can be counter productive and make him more clingy.

Whatever you do, try not to get into a fight with him over this. This is very very hard, particularly when you're super-tired yourself. However it really does have exactly the opposite effect to what you want.

Comment: Thank you! I started trying this last night. I made another bed next to his twin size bed just to let him getting used to not having me sleeping next to him during the whole night.... He woke up maybe a million times last night calling me, so basically I was hanging myself on his bed... LOL. It won't happen over one night and I'm prepared. Thank you for your comment!